# Sharepoint 2013 Crawling doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawl

My farm contains 2 web server , 2 app servers

Recently, I have created a new web application and start for config the search services.

when I started crawling and got following error message :
`https://x xxxx.domain.com`

> An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl
>   this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser.
>   ( Error from SharePoint site: WebExceptionStatus: TrustFailure The
>   underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; SearchID =
>   C799330E-6C61-4123-A663-DEB0DEC59586 )

1. Two web server still blinding a new ip address and cert
2. SharePoint create the trust cert on it
3. Two app server can access the new site with using search and crawling account. but when i try to access the site in app server with Search account that show me no any access right, i check the user permission in web application. the search account has full read permission but i still add a new user with search account on it and success access the site. however, when i start crawling the error is still here.
4. I tried to config the AAM `http://xxx  https://xxxx`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does your primary AAM for the site match what is in the content source URL list? These need to match or it won't work as there'll be a mismatch between the actual URL and the one it is indexing with.

Also check that the crawling account can access the resource without being presented with a login box (check from the server running the crawl component). In our farm we have all the webapps set as Intranet Zone sites with the logon option set to 'Automatically use current username and password in Intranet zone'.

Comment: Since this web app is new application, the farm still has two old web app is running and crawling success from this search account. so i don't think is about any IE security setting. AAM removed that i check it is correct. Really thanks your comment.

Comment: I would still check your IE settings - if it is a new web app the URL might not be included in the sites definition for the zone.